# Adding a submodule in a Project, Can't see it in Xcode, but See it in terminal

Tags: ios, xcode, git, git-submodules

I have been trying to build a proof of concept for how submoduling works.

I have created 2 projects:

One called **Core** - Which contains a custom view which turns red.

And one project called: **Test**.

I want to pull **Core**, into test, and use a class in Core to update my view Controller to be red.

I have been reading this guide for help:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

After adding the submodule to Test. I can see it in Git, and I have ran the init, init --recursive,

but when I open Test.xcodeproj - I do not see Core in there, nor am I able to interact with any of the classes in core.

How do I properly use submoduling to achieve what i'm looking for?